# Migration from SP2010 to SP2013 bug: custom site columns mess up

Tags: migration, site-column

I am migrating a site collection from SP2010 to SP2013 using content database attachment method. After attached and running the site in SP2010 mode it is working fine. However, after creata a SP2013-evaluation site collection, I found some site columns are missed.

After further study, by using PowerShell I can locate the missed columns. They are all messed up.

New SP2013-eval custom content type using those columns:

```
<FieldTitle>    <Field Internal name>
News Category   ExpiryDate
News Location   PublishingIsFurlPage
News Priority   SeoKeywords
```

Old SP2010:

```
News Category   NewsCategory
News Location   NewsLocation
News Priority   NewsPriority
```

(The field title using is actually Chinese Character. I translated them here)
As you can see, the custom column messed up.

May I know is it a known issue? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution assoicated with those site columns. I rebuild the solution by changing the manifest xml as below:

[image: change from 14.0 to 15.0]

Then uninstall the old wsp, install the new wsp. Those site columns become valid again.